# Is there a setting that determines the default root folder of a freshly-created SPList?

Tags: list, splist

I noticed that when I create lists on my development site(s), they're created right in the site's root (in other words, URLs look like xxx/sites/DEV/DocLibX).

The last time I looked (a few days ago), lists were automatically created under Lists (URLs looked like xxx/sites/DEV/Lists/DocLibY) - which is how I'd like to keep it.

Far as I can tell, this issue relates to all sites within the web application (both existing ones AND newly-created ones).

There isn't anything specific I can think of that I did to alter my development environment.

Has anyone here seen this issue appear and, if so, found a solution for it?

TIA
Josh

Answer (score 0):

By design document libraries get the first URL you mention while generic and other list types gets the second URL you mention.

Are you sure you used the same list type when you created those two lists?

Comment: Absolutely. The codebase is exactly the same in both the before and after situations. 

And I'm positive that document libraries get created in Lists/